# Error while creating a new file in Android: FileNotFoundException: /test.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: android, file, filenotfoundexception

I have a png file in the raw folder. I get the inputStream using :

```
inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```

I am trying to write this inputStream in a new file in an Android application. This is my code:

```
                inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
                File file = new File("/test.png");
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*1024];

                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
```

When I run the application, I get the following error in the logcat:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /test.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Basically I want to create a File object so that I can send this to my server.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have access to the file-system root, which is what you're attempting to access. For your purposes, you can write to internal files `new File("test.png")`, which places the file in the application-internal storage -- better yet, access it explicitly using `getFilesDir()`.

For truly temporary files, you might want to look into `getCacheDir()` -- should you forget to delete those temporary files, the system will reclaim the space when it runs out of room.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
                inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.earth);
                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.png");
                file.createNewFile();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*1024];
                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
```